# Yii access rule redirection with parameters

Tags: yii

In the Yii application i am creating i have a search functionality. In this any user(authenticated  and guest) can see the searchbox. but when i click the search button only logged in user can see the result. else it will be redirected to login screen . once they login they can see the result.

So I have written accessrule like this

```
return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('search'),
            'users'=>array('@')
        ),
```

My doubt is when it is coming to the search action there are 2 parameters(POST)(my search keywords). when it goes to loginurl  and come back after my successful login to same action How can i get these keywords back  ?
Is there any direct yii  method other than to use session ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest making your search form to use `GET`, not `POST`, of course this will depend on use cases and requirements, but search forms should use `GET` to make them more usable & accessible. This should also fix your problem because then Yii will return to the search results URL after login (depending on the code, might not always work).

If you have to use `POST` then the only way I can see is to make a filter method which will save the keywords to session.

Answer (score 0):

I would have done so:

1. set allow for guest 'users'=>array('*')
2. In search action if user is guest store search keywords in session, redirect user to login form, and after returned check method if not POST and in session stored keywords - get search keywords from session and searching.

Comment: i want only authenticated users to see the result. the result is fetched in actionSearch, that is why i have given it as '@', But any one can see the searchbar.

Comment: @MaheshEu, i updated my answer. And take a point for answer Andrew M.